# member function obtains copy of shared pointer to class instance

Tags: c++11, shared-ptr

I am moving to using C++11 shared pointers.

I need to write member functions that adds pointers to the instance of their class to containers ( i.e. registers ( adds ) their presence in some collection )

Using plain old pointers, I can do this

```
class myClass {
public:
    void Register( std::vector< myClass* >& v_registrants )
    {
        v_registrants.push_back( this );
    }
};
```

But how to do the same when the collection holds shared pointers?  Somehow the member function must obtain a copy of the shared pointer that owns the instance.

I cannot simply create a new shared pointer from this because:

*If two shared_ptr are constructed (or made) from the same (non-shared_ptr) pointer, they will both be owning the pointer without sharing it, causing potential access problems when one of them releases it (deleting its managed object) and leaving the other pointing to an invalid location.* ( [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/) )

So, what to do to implement the following class?

```
class myClass_safe {
public:
    void Register( std::vector< std::shared_ptr<myClass_safe > >& v_registrants )
    {
        //v_registrants.push_back( this );  // compiler freaks out
    }
};
```

As a workaround, I am doing this:

```
class myClass_safe {
public:
    void Register( 
        std::shared_ptr<myClass_safe >& my_shared_ptr,
        std::vector< std::shared_ptr<myClass_safe > >& v_registrants )
    {
        v_registrants.push_back( my_shared_ptr );  
    }
};
```

Which results in this rather strange code

```
// register the object
object->Register( object, v_registrants );
```

Is there not something better than this?

Comment: Have you already tried using [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this)?

Comment: Btw, this sounds like complicated ownership. Maybe you can simplify the design (XY-problem?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is exactly what [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this) is intended for.

Inheriting from `std::enable_shared_from_this<classname>` provides your class with a member function called [`shared_from_this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/shared_from_this), that enables you to safely obtain a `std::shared_ptr` that shares ownership with the original owner.

So to use it, in your case, you would have to change your class definition like this:

```
class myClass_safe : public std::enable_shared_from_this<myClass_safe> {
public:
    void Register( std::vector< std::shared_ptr<myClass_safe > >& v_registrants )
    {
        v_registrants.push_back( shared_from_this() );
    }
};
```

**Note also, that the object must be owned by a shared pointer prior to calling shared_from_this.**